# Does Hooke's Law apply to all springs?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, string, elasticity, linearized-theory

I understand that Hooke's Law is $F=-kx$, and that this law only applies when a spring is not "overstreched." However, does Hooke's Law apply to **all** springs, or only simple harmonic oscillating springs?

To take it a step further, what is a simple harmonic oscillator defined as?

Comment: Not only to springs, but only in linear approximation... just like many similar "laws" - see for examples in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/570483/247642)

Comment: Closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/459711/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60648/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331632/226902

Comment: I'd that Hooke's law, by definition, works for all and only springs that obey it. It _induces_ the spring as a theoretical/model concept, the one that counteracts a force proportionally to its displacement. I wouldn't risk putting this down as an answer, both fully precise and useless. The theory induces an ideal spring model, but real world springs are very not the things studied by this theory. First, they have a mass... (As an exercise, solve motion of an ideal spring with constant linear mass density w/o a mass at end. :) ) But, as always is on PhysSO, the answers are amazing!

Comment: And yeah, you're totally right, 1-D SHM is _defined_ by the 2nd order ODE $m\ddot{x}=-k x$. No springs or Hooke's law required. :)

Comment: If Hooke's Law applies not to all springs, but only to simple harmonic oscillating springs, what reason would you use to explain that?

To take it a step further, what do you think a simple harmonic oscillator defined as?

Comment: Hooke's law applies to to all objects over a small enough displacement, but that displacement can be very small indeed! Springs which closely obey Hooke's law for large displacements are carefully manufactured to do that. This makes them useful for things like watches, clocks, and other mechanical devices if this property is needed...

Comment: "what is a simple harmonic oscillator defined as?" - "simple harmonic" just means that there's something that changes periodically in a sinusoidal (sine or cosine) pattern over time. You examine the system and you see if you can find some variable that behaves like that - that is, something that traces a sine wave over time: e.g. horizontal position coordinate of a pendulum, angular displacement in a torsional oscillator, current in an LC circuit.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are springs explicitly designed to deviate from Hooke's law in a repeatable and predictable manner.

[image]
[(image credit)](https://metalcloak.blogspot.com/2013/12/understanding-suspension-spring.html)

In this example, this is done without using the possible intrinsic non-linearities of the material. The steel itself is used well inside its Hooke-abiding deformation range in order to be acceptably reliable.

So the short answer is No.

Like many empirical laws in Physics, Hooke's law only approximates the elastic bodies behavior.

In regard to the harmonic oscillator: this is an **idealized model**.

A simple spring with a massive object on one end and the other end held stationary behaves more or less as a harmonic oscillator if one is careful to excite it exactly longitudinally and not to excite it too much.

Comment: I like the picture! One of those worth $N$ words! :-)

Comment: @kkm Answers with useful or relevant pictures routinely earn more upvotes than text-only answers.

Comment: All these springs still behave linearly for small enough displacements. The fact that you have non linear response for finite displacement is quite general and it' s true also for less "exotic" springs.

Comment: @Quillo they can be made non-linear for arbitrary small displacements. And yes, the materials themselves are non-linear by their very nature.

Comment: @Quillo When you say that, do you really mean to say that force as a function of displacement is differentiable? Because that's how I would interpret a statement like "it is linear for small enough deltas"

Comment: @Arthur: you can always write $F=-k(x)x$, for any spring/material, where $k$ is not a constant. For small enough $x$, $k(x)\approx k_0 + k_1 x+...$, the smaller the $x$ the better is the approximation $k(x)\approx k_0 $, that is Hooke's law. I am claiming that the fact that there are non-zero $k_1, k_2....$ is not incredible or unexpected. I am saying that I am not able to find any example of a physical system with $k_0=0$, namely a system that deviates from Hooke for any $x$, no matter how small. See Puk's answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/754066/226902

Comment: @Quillo, As I mentioned in another comment, repeating for completeness here: it is very possible to have (nominally) constant-force springs for which your $k_0$ (which is really $k_1$ because you have prefactored out one instance of $x$) is zero.

Comment: @Quillo Here’s a link: https://www.leespring.com/learn-about-constant-force-springs. My point is that because springs can have a force term that is independent of $x$, we should have $F = k_{0} + k_{1}x + x_{2}x^2 …$, with the number on k corresponding to the power to which x is raised, rather than pre-factoring by $x$ and offsetting the $k$-number and $x$-power by one from each other.

Comment: k0 is zero by definition if x=0 is the rest (equilibrium) position. Constant force springs are called that way just because are pre-loaded and do not start from an equilibrium position: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-force_spring

Comment: @Quillo The Wikipedia explanation is wrong, or at least deficient. Constant-force springs have a fundamentally different behavior than just taking a simple coil spring, preloading it, and looking at deformations that are small relative to the preload. The kinematics of the coil mean that most of the spring is out-of-action at any given time and the energy in the spring is directly proportional to its extension. (Physical construction of this ideal condition is to use bearings to keep the extended position straight, or back-wind it around a second drum in a constant-torque configuration.)

Comment: (The Wikipedia article appears to have been correct from 2015 to 2018, at which point it was edited to replace the correct explanation of the mechanics (material coming off the roll contributing to the bending energy, and material further away already pulled straight and not changing shape as the spring extends) with the incorrect idea that the spring is just a preloaded long-travel spring. I’ve reverted that edit.)

Comment: @RLH  look at this graph https://www.vulcanspring.com/blog/constant-force-springs-explained/ : even "constant force" springs are "Hookean" for small displacements.

Comment: @Quillo That graph is for a constant-force spring with a "free span" from the loading point to the spool. The initial Hookean section corresponds to the formation of the arch between the spool and the asymptotically straight section. If you feed the spring into a guide that stops it from curling up once it is off the spool, you can make the Hookean region arbitrarily small. ...

Comment: (In a physical system, you need a way to hang onto the free end. This can either be a pre-displacement or a pre-bent end-piece on the strip as at https://www.vulcanspring.com/blog/design-study-spool-mounted-constant-force-springs-used-for-dampened-linear-motion/)

Comment: In any case, parameterizing a constant-force spring with $x=0$ in the Hookean region requires defining the spring force with a high-order Taylor series to handle the zero-rate behavior in the operating region, or putting $x=0$ in the operating region and using $F=k_0$ across the operating region.

Answer (score 17):

Hooke's law is valid for all springs when they are not "overstretched" (except possibly one designed specifically not to obey it, more on that in a bit). This also applies to other systems with a position-dependent restoring force (not just springs). However, such systems differ in how far you can stretch them before they begin to violate Hooke's law.

Suppose the spring force is some function $F(x)$, where $x=0$ is the equilibrium position, i.e. $F(0) = 0$. The Taylor expansion around $x=0$ gives
$$ F(x) = F'(0)x + \frac{F''(0)}{2!}x^2+\frac{F'''(0)}{3!}x^3+\ldots$$
If $F'(0)$ is not zero (I know of no example where it is zero, but perhaps it's possible to design such a spring?), by definition, the spring constant is $k=-F'(0)$. Note that for small displacements, terms of order $>1$ will be much smaller that the "Hooke's law" term of order $1$, so the spring will obey Hooke's law.

You may then ask "for what range of displacements does the spring obey Hooke's law"? This will depend on the spring. If the second term is greater than terms of higher order when the spring becomes overstretched, the condition for the validity of Hooke's law is that the first term be much greater in magnitude than the second, which requires
$$|x|\ll\frac{2k}{|F''(0)|}.$$

It may happen that $F''(0)$ is small enough that the linear range of the spring is determined by the third order term. To understand why, note that the second order term is either always positive or always negative, depending on the sign of $F''(0)$. This means that whichever way you extend the spring, the corresponding force is always in the same direction (not always toward the equilibrium position). Springs do not behave this way, so the second order term is often small compared to the third, or perhaps comparable.

In this case, Hooke's law's validity also requires that the third order term be much smaller in magnitude than the first, which is equivalent to the condition
$$|x|\ll\sqrt{\frac{6k}{|F'''(0)|}}.$$

Comment: To be a little more glib about it:  springs obey Hooke's Law until they're "overstretched" because we define "overstretched" to be the point where they stop obeying Hooke's Law.

Comment: ... It requires the sum of 2nd through infinite order terms be much smaller than the first order term.  Which is stating "when it obeys hook's law" in more words.

Comment: @Yakk This is not particularly helpful when you know $F(x)$ and want to calculate the range of applicability of Hooke's law. Usually the first one or two terms after the linear term dominate when the spring begins to deviate from Hooke's law, so the rest can be neglected. But the point of the first half of this answer is simply that Hooke's law is very generally valid for small displacements.

Comment: Best answer IMO. The real interesting point is not what happens at large displacements (the fact that a nonlinear regime has to be expected for large displacement  is obvious) but rather if there is an example of spring that has no linear term for small displacement. This would be a really interesting "non-Hookean" spring. I am not able to find a single example.

Comment: @Quillo, yeah, and also consider spring's own mass, inelastic losses, spring's own resonant properties (you'll inevitably induce a wave when compressing a spring; this can be ignored only if its time scale is much different from the harmonic oscillator period), and the motion that's not artificially constrained to the spring's axis. Real helical springs don't like to be compressed without buckling... It's hard to grok whether the question is about an ideal oscillation, or a realistic spring.

Comment: This answer is mostly good, but assumes that the $F^0$ term is non-zero. A constant-force spring (instantiated as a coiled strip of metal) has a non-zero $F^0$ term and nominally zero $F'$ and higher terms.

Comment: @RLH $x = 0$ is the equilibrium position where by definition $F(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Puk: Where is the equilibrium position for a spring with force equation $F=1$?

Comment: @RLH If the force of a spring (or a system thereof) is not zero, it is not in equilibrium. It will move toward the equilibrium position once you let it go. Surely an equation like $F(x) = 1$ doesn't describe a spring around its equilibrium/rest position.

Comment: @Puk: that’s my point: there are springs that are constant force and thus don’t have an equilibrium position at which the constant term goes away. (In practice, the forces are step functions in which there is between zero force and their nominal force when they are completely retracted, and then hold constant force once extending).

Comment: Just to clarify: @RLH is referring to this interesting king of spring,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-force_spring : the "constant force" comes from a pre-loaded rest position, so that the initial force stsrts from a finite value. For small variations around this initial position the force is approximately constant. Note: if you start from a non equilibrium position the force is nearly constant in a small $dx$ for, literally, any spring, unless there is a discontinuity in $F$ at that position. However for this kind of "spring" the "constant" region is quite extended and this is cool.

Comment: As detailed in my comment on the other message (and in my answer), the Wikipedia article incorrect/deficient, and the force-curve on a constant-force spring is fundamentally different from that of a preloaded linear spring. The preloaded linear spring stores energy as $E=\frac{1}{2}Kx_{0}^{2} + \frac{1}{2}Kx_{\delta}^{2} + Kx_{0}x_{\delta}$, whereas the constant-force spring’s energy storage is asymptotically $E=Kx_{\text{extension}}$, with K being proportional to the product of the material’s bending stiffness and the squared curvature of the spooled portion of the spring.

Comment: (The Wikipedia article appears to have been correct from 2015 to 2018, at which point it was edited to replace the correct explanation of the mechanics (material coming off the roll contributing to the bending energy, and material further away already pulled straight and not changing shape as the spring extends) with the incorrect idea that the spring is just a preloaded long-travel spring. I’ve reverted that edit.)

Answer (score 14):

Hooke's law applies only to springy things where the deflection response is *linear*, as in the case for small deflections of *elastic solids*.

It does *not* apply for *nonlinear springs* like that represented by a piston in a cylinder full of gas or a length of rubber band.

A simple harmonic oscillator (SHM) can be defined as a *second order dynamical system* which contains energy storage elements whose constituitive relations are *linear* in the applicable flow and effort variables, and *not* functions of time, displacement, or velocity. The solution of the resulting differential equations of motion will then be a sine or cosine function versus time.

Comment: Is there any real example of springs that are intrinsically nonlinear (i.e. no linear term in the Taylor expansion of the force in the displacement)? E.g something that follows https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331632/226902

Comment: Such a spring is called *constituitively nonlinear*, I do not know if there are no linear terms in the taylor expansion of for example a gas spring which has a constituitive law based on the ideal gas law. -NN

Comment: Thank you. Simple calculation for a piston filled with ideal gas shows a linear term (for both adiabatic or isothermal oscillations).

Comment: Crossing over from comments I left on other answers — constant force springs of the form $F=k$ are theoretically feasible (and I can buy reasonable physical instantiations of them from McMaster)

Answer (score -1):

Hooke’s law for mechanical springs is the large-scale effect of the intermolecular forces in the material following an $F=-K_{m}x_m$ rule for small displacements between the molecules.

When you apply a force to one end of the spring, each pair of molecules displaces proportionally to this force, and the end of the spring moves by the sum of these displacements. (The full force at the end of the spring is applied to each cross-section of the spring —- forces are transmitted through the structure, not “absorbed” by intermediate pieces.)

(The above description is directly applicable to springs that are “sticks” being stretched or compressed along their lengths. For a coil spring, pulling on the ends of the spring causes all of the wire pieces to twist, which pushes and pulls molecules against each other. A few extra “lever arms” get involved in the calculations, related to the radius of the wire and the radius and pitch of the coil, but the overall idea is the same. For a leaf spring, the molecules are moved relative to each other when the spring bends.)

For springs in which the material has a “uniform” distribution (like a coil with constant radius and pitch), the internal deformation is evenly distributed, with the result that the displacement between any pair of molecules (and thus the force in the spring) is proportional to the total displacement of the end of the spring. This then becomes Hooke’s law for simple springs, $F=-K_{s}x$

It is possible to alter the geometry of the spring to get nonlinear springs. In @fraxinus’s answer, the progressive-rate spring has a coil that becomes “flatter” near the top. These parts twist more easily when force is applied at the end of the spring. On its own, this change in winding pitch just means that we need to take into account the different “lever arms” at different parts of the coil when calculating the total stiffness. Because they move more easily, however, the flatter coils will start to touch each other as the spring  compresses; this “takes them out of play” by preventing them from compressing any more, so further displacement is distributed over a shorter section of the spring, so that the ratio between movement of the end of the the spring and the intermolecular displacements gets larger. This makes the spring force increase as faster than linearly as the spring is compressed. The exact rate at which the force goes up (i.e. the coefficients in the series that appear in other answers) depends on the winding pattern of the spring.

For the dual-rate spring in @fraxinus’s answer, the flat set of coils bottom out all at once, so that the total stiffness is the combination of the two stiffnesses (dominated by the softer of the two values) for small displacements, and then abruptly changes to the stiffer spring rate when the soft spring is fully compressed.

[“Combining” spring stiffnesses in series actually follows the rule $1/K = 1/K_1 + 1/K_2$, such that the combined spring stiffness is smaller than either of the individual springs, and is approximately the stiffness of the softer spring when the springs are of very different stiffness.]

It is also possible to make a “constant force” spring in which the spring force is independent of the extension of the spring. A common construction is a spool of metal tape that is heat treated after winding so that its resting configuration is the coiled shape. Putting this coil on a spindle and then pulling the free end away from the coil will result in most of the unspooled section being pulled straight, with a short curved region transitioning between the spooled and straight sections. Pulling on the end of the tape doesn’t bend the straight section, so the straight section is “out of play” like the bottomed out coils, with the result that the retraction force from the spring trying to spool itself back up is independent of how much material has been unspooled, and thus is independent of the displacement of the end of the spring.

(Many of these ideas, especially the structure of the constant-force spring can be expressed more rigorously if we start by saying that the spring rate is the derivative with respect to displacement of the energy stored in the system, but this appears to be a bit above the level at which the question was being asked.)

Comment: Downvoter: What do you disagree with in my answer?